# Cells won't show in UICollectionView

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview

I'm trying to create a `UICollectionView` and display few cells there.

This is my code:

```
    class MainVC: UIViewController, UICollectionViewDelegate, UICollectionViewDataSource {

        var mForecast = [CustomCollectionViewCell]()

        let CVCellIdentifier = "forecastCell"

        lazy var mCollectionView: UICollectionView = {

            var collectionView = UICollectionView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 300, height: 150), collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewFlowLayout())
            collectionView.clipsToBounds = true
            collectionView.backgroundColor = .red

            collectionView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
            return collectionView

        }()

        override func viewDidLoad() {

            super.viewDidLoad()
            view.backgroundColor = UIColor(red: 80/255, green: 135/255, blue: 179/255, alpha: 1.0)

            setupNavBar()
            self.navigationItem.searchController = mSearchBarController

            setupMainWeatherIcon()
            fillArrayWithData()
            mCollectionView.register(CustomCollectionViewCell.self, forCellWithReuseIdentifier: CVCellIdentifier)
            mCollectionView.dataSource = self
            mCollectionView.delegate = self

        }

    private func fillArrayWithData(){
        for _ in 1...6 {
            let forecastCell: ForecastCell = ForecastCell()

            forecastCell.mDayLabel = "DAY-TEST"
            forecastCell.mWeatherIcon = UIImage(named: "partly-cloudy")
            forecastCell.mTempLabel = "TEMP-TEST"

            mForecast.append(forecastCell)
        }

        mCollectionView.reloadData()
    }
        //MARK: COLLECTION VIEW METHODS
        func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {

            return mForecast.count

        }

        func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
            let cell = mCollectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: CVCellIdentifier, for: indexPath) as! CustomCollectionViewCell

            return cell
        }
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize {
        return CGSize(width: (view.frame.width / 6) - 16 , height: 70)

    }

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout              
      collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, insetForSectionAt  
      section: Int) -> UIEdgeInsets {
        return UIEdgeInsets(top: 10, left: 8, bottom: 10, right: 8)
      }
    }
```

This is the CustomCollectionViewCell class:

```
import UIKit

class CustomCollectionViewCell: UICollectionViewCell {
    var mDayLabel: String?
    var mWeatherIcon: UIImage?
    var mTempLabel: String?

let dayTV: UILabel = {

    var label = UILabel()
    label.textAlignment = .center
    label.font = UIFont.boldSystemFont(ofSize: 12)
    label.textColor = .blue

    label.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    return label

}()

let weatherImg: UIImageView = {

    var img = UIImageView()

    img.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    return img

}()

let tempLabel: UILabel = {

    var label = UILabel()
    label.textAlignment = .center
    label.font = UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 8)
    label.textColor = .blue

    label.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    return label

}()

override init(frame: CGRect) {
    super.init(frame: frame)
}

required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
    fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
}

override func layoutSubviews() {
    super.layoutSubviews()

    if let label = mDayLabel{
        dayTV.text = label
    }
    if let image = mWeatherIcon{
        weatherImg.image = image
    }
    if let temp = mTempLabel{
        tempLabel.text = temp
    }

    setupDayTextView()
    setupWeatherImage()
    setupTempLabel()

}

private func setupDayTextView(){

    addSubview(dayTV)

    dayTV.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.centerXAnchor).isActive = true
    dayTV.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.topAnchor, constant: 10).isActive = true

}

private func setupWeatherImage(){

    addSubview(weatherImg)

    weatherImg.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.centerXAnchor).isActive = true
    weatherImg.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: dayTV.bottomAnchor, constant: 10).isActive = true

}

private func setupTempLabel(){

    addSubview(tempLabel)

    tempLabel.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.centerXAnchor).isActive = true
    tempLabel.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: weatherImg.bottomAnchor, constant: 10).isActive = true

}
}
```

Of course I have a method to fill `mForecast` array with data, if I add a subview I do see the cell, but I know I shouldn't do that to view the cells inside the collection view.

I tried looking but couldn't find what's wrong here and why the cells won't be displayed.
This is what I get

[image]

Comment: How is "coded" `CustomCollectionViewCell`? Do you use a separated xib? If that's the case, you should register the Nib, not only the class. It is just code? What's supposed to be there?

Comment: What is your mForecast.count?

Comment: Where you are getting for mForecast ? Are you trying to reload the data of collectionView once you assign the data to  mForecast ?

Comment: mForecast is a array to store the cells. mForecast Is an array of type CustomCollectionViewCell. and mForecast.count value is 6.

Comment: @Sateesh it's a simple method just filling the array with image and string for now. just to test if I can display the cells, which I can't.

Comment: @Larme My bad for not including this class. I'm editing the OP now and adding.

Comment: You are creating the collectionView programmatically but not adding it as a subview to the view of view controller. I wonder how would it show any content on the screen.

Comment: @Adeel I do add it to the screen, just didn't put the code here as I think it's less relevant.

Comment: Have debugged the view hierarchy?

Comment: @Adeel no, I'm really new to all of this and I don't really know how.

Comment: Follow this tutorial to get a better understanding of view hierarchy debugger https://www.raywenderlich.com/1879-view-debugging-in-xcode-6

Comment: Do you see any error in the logs?

Comment: Actually, no. Simply not showing.

Answer (score 0):

ORIGINAL:

After setting the delegate and the datasource, you need to call `collectionView.reloadData()`

REVISED:

You are calling `fillArrayWithData`, which calls `reloadData` before you finish configuring the collectionView's datasource and delegate. Thus, when `reloadData` is called, there is no source that sets the data and loads the cells.

Try calling your `fillArrayWithData` after you finalize the configuration of your collection view.

I personally recommend configuring your collection view in `viewDidLoad` or in the `didSet` property observer of collectionView:

```
var collectionView: UICollectionView! {
     didSet {
         collectionView.delegate = self
         collectionView.dataSource = self
     }
}
```

And then I initiate the load of the data in my `viewWillAppear` method.

EXAMPLE:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {

        super.viewDidLoad()
        view.backgroundColor = UIColor(red: 80/255, green: 135/255, blue: 179/255, alpha: 1.0)

        setupNavBar()
        self.navigationItem.searchController = mSearchBarController

        setupMainWeatherIcon()

        // This is where you are calling fillArrayWithData right now.
        // fillArrayWithData()

        mCollectionView.register(CustomCollectionViewCell.self, forCellWithReuseIdentifier: CVCellIdentifier)
        mCollectionView.dataSource = self
        mCollectionView.delegate = self

        // This is where you should be calling fillArrayWithData
        fillArrayWithData()

    }
```

Comment: Thanks, but the cells still won't show. The collection view is scrollable, which to me sounds like the cells are added to the collection view but won't be displayed

Comment: Where are you actually adding cells into the `var mForecast = [CustomCollectionViewCell]()` array? I see you initialize it as an empty array, but I don't see where you are actually creating and inserting instances of `CustomCollectionViewCell` into that array.

Comment: I'm adding the function to the OP now. Didn't think it's relevant.

Comment: Okay, and where is that `fillArrayWithData` function being called? In the `viewDidLoad`, `viewWillAppear?`, etc.?

Comment: It's in viewDidLoad

Comment: Oh I see it now (your OP is ill-formatted FYI). But it looks like you are calling `fillArrayWithData` BEFORE you set the delegate and the datasource of the collection view. So when that function runs, and calls `reloadData`, that is all occurring before the datasource/delegate are set, thus it doesn't have a datasource/delegate to pull from.

Comment: Tried to reformat it to be little better. I edited it few times so it happened, sorry. I tried now calling fillArrayWithData before setupCollectionView and moved the reload() method to the setupCollectionView, still won't show.. I'm thinking about deleting all of this and start over with a tutorial, is it a good idea? or should I try to fix this?

Comment: no, you don't need to do that. I revised my answer for a suggested solution. I will revise again with an example.

Comment: Thanks, I tried but it still won't show. Maybe if I will start over I will follow carefully and then build it, first the background and then image etc.

Comment: before doing that make sure you undo what you said you did: `I tried now calling fillArrayWithData` before setUpCollectionView and moved the reload().....` and try my example based off of the code in your question

Comment: Also, in your `fillArrayWithData` function, you are initializing a `ForecastCell` not a `CustomCollectionViewCell`. Make sure the cells you are attempting to load are of the same type that is in the data it is loading from

Comment: Thank you very much! I really appreciate it. I tried but It won't work, I guess I'm doing something else wrong, I will just start over. Thanks again!

Comment: Yeah, I just refactored that, Thanks :)